# 'docker cp' from docker container to jenkins workspace during build

Tags: docker, jenkins

Is there a way I can copy files from docker container to jenkins workspace while tests are running i.e. not pre- or post- build

Currently docker is on a server within the organisation and when I kick off a Jenkins job (maven project), it runs tests within the above container.

During the test, there are files downloaded and I would like to be able to access those files in the jenkins workspace, during execution. So I tried the following as part of my code:

```
docker cp [containerName]:/home/seluser/Downloads /var/jenkins_home/jobs/[jobName]/workspace
```

But the files don't get copied over to the workspace. I have also tried doing this locally, i.e. getting the files copied to a directory on my laptop:

```
docker cp [containerName]:/home/seluser/Downloads /Users/[myUsername]/testDownloads
```

and it worked. Is there something I'm missing regarding how to do this for jenkins workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/.` as :

```
docker cp [containerName]:/home/seluser/Downloads/. /var/jenkins_home/jobs/[jobName]/workspace/
```